# how can i set validation for multi select list in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0, multi-select

I have a form with multi select box:

```
echo $this->Form->input('emp_id',       array(  'options' => array( $arr),
                                                                'empty' => '(choose one)',
                                                                'div'=>'formfield',
                                                                'error' => array(   'wrap' => 'div',
                                                                                    'class' => 'formerror'
                                                                                ),
                                                                'label' => 'Team Members',
                                                                'type' => 'select', 'multiple' => true,
                                                                'style' => 'width:210px; height:125px;'
                                                        ));
```

I selected multiple values from this list box and click the `SAVE` button.

But it displays the validation message.

How can i solve this?

```
class TravancoDSRGroup extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'TravancoDSRGroup'; 
        var $useTable = 'dsr_group'; // This model uses a database table 'exmp'
        var $validate = array(
                    'emp_id' => array(
                            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                            'message' => 'The employee field is required'
                    )
            );

}
```

This is the model code....

If it is possible...?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly specify

```
'type' => 'select'
```

if you set 'emps' from the controller, it will allow cake's automagic to work. just add

```
$this->set(compact('emps'));
```

Post output of **debug($this->request->data)** for better understanding of problem.

Have you defined hasMany or HABTM relationships to the emp ? To have multiple values saved you will have to define hasMany or HABTM relations, if you wish to save it as CSV then you will have to do the processing yourself in 'beforeSave'.